# How to format a date that is a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array of objects:

```js
var exerciseLog = [{“date”:“2019-07-02T21:18:48.946Z”,“description”:“pull ups”,“duration”:“90”},{“date”:“2019-07-02T21:22:30.395Z”,“description”:“push ups”,“duration”:“90”},{“date”:“2019-07-02T22:19:37.790Z”,“description”:“push ups”,“duration”:“50”}]
```

I want to format the date to exclude the time so the date is either displayed as "YYYY-MM-DD" or "YYYY/MM/DD".

I've tried map, forEach, slice, splice.

```
exerciseLog = exerciseLog.forEach(x => x.date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Doesn't work in the relevant portion of the code:

```
app.get("/api/exercise/log", function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.query.userId; 
    var from = req.query.from ? new Date(req.query.from) : new Date("1970-01-01");
    var to = req.query.to ? new Date(req.query.to) : new Date();

    User.findById(userId, function (err, doc) {
      if (!doc) {
        res.send({ "error": "userId not found" });
      } else {
        var exerciseLog = doc.exercises.sort((a, b) => a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime())
          .filter(x => x.date >= from && x.date <= to);
        var limit = !isNaN(req.query.limit) ? req.query.limit : exerciseLog.length;
        exerciseLog = exerciseLog.slice(0, limit);
        exerciseLog = exerciseLog.forEach(x => x.date.toLocaleDateString());
        res.send({ "username": doc.username, "Exercise Count": exerciseLog.length, "Exercise Log": exerciseLog });
      }
    });
  });
```

The error:

```
events.js:160
6:59 PM
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
6:59 PM
      ^
6:59 PM
6:59 PM
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
6:59 PM
Jump to
at /app/server.js:138:77
6:59 PM
    at /rbd/pnpm-volume/52232b84-c31b-4266-9261-f25b6365dff7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/5.6.2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4846:16
6:59 PM
    at /rbd/pnpm-volume/52232b84-c31b-4266-9261-f25b6365dff7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/5.6.2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4283:12
6:59 PM
    at process.nextTick (/rbd/pnpm-volume/52232b84-c31b-4266-9261-f25b6365dff7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/5.6.2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2776:28)
6:59 PM
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
6:59 PM
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Which points to this line:

```
var limit = !isNaN(req.query.limit) ? req.query.limit : exerciseLog.length;
```

but if I remove the code with the forEach line I have no errors.

Full code https://glitch.com/edit/#!/swamp-liquid?path=server.js:138:53.

Comment: Your current input's syntax is invalid. Try to avoid using curly quotes in programming, they often create problems

Comment: @CertainPerformance?  I'm not sure what you mean?  In my question that is how the array is displayed when it is sent as a response from my database, and everything functions correctly except that I would like the response from the database date to be formated.

Comment: Just try pressing "Run code snippet" at the top - the code you posted throws a syntax error.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying.  The curly quotes are not in my code, they got there from copying and pasting and I did not notice that they pasted as curly quotes.  In my code they are regular quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Your bug is because you are assigning the return value from [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to `exerciseLog`.

Array.prototype.forEach does not return anything.

You want to use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

`exerciseLog = exerciseLog.map(x => x.date.toLocaleDateString());`

Comment: When I try your suggested code, I get "Uncaught TypeError: x.date.toLocaleDateString is not a function". Any thoughts on what might be happening? Thank you.

Comment: @ND_Coder I didn't leave an executable example here and I didn't provide an example object array with dates in it. What ever array you are mapping does not contain objects with a date property. Maybe you need to construct some dates? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Thank you for your insights. You were right. The array of objects was JSON so the date field was a string. The only way I've discovered that works (after some time experimenting) is to first turn the date string BACK to a date object using (et x_dates = log.map(x => new Date(x.date); and then apply your code but this seems wrong somehow. I need to compare (==) the output of this calculation with data already in '.toLocaleDateString' format.

Comment: Just do it inline: exerciseLog = exerciseLog.map(x => new Date(x.date).toLocaleDateString());

Comment: This is brilliant! Works perfectly. Had not tried that combination. Much appreciated. I learned something here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Miles Grover and @BlueWater86 thank you for the help.  I tried map before and it didn't work but now it does.

```
exerciseLog = exerciseLog.map(x => x.date.toLocaleDateString());
```

returned only the formatted dates, so I had to do this to keep the rest of the object info:

```
exerciseLog = exerciseLog.map(x => "description: " + x.description + ", duration: " + x.duration + ", date: " + x.date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exerciseLog = exerciseLog.forEach(x => x.date.toLocaleDateString());
```

`forEach()` doesn't return anything, so you're setting `exerciseLog` to null or undefined. If you use `map()` instead, that line will set `exerciseLog` to a new array based on what's returned in the function you pass to `map()`.

The next issue is that the quotes in your original code snippet are curly quotes -- not sure where that's coming from, but nothing is going to work until those are single or double straight quotes.

I think the last issue is that `x.date` is already a date string, not a Date object, so `toLocaleDateString()` won't work on it. You may be able to just use `x.date`, or if you do need to convert the date to a different locale, you'd do something like `new Date(x.date).toLocaleDateString()`.